# How to sort the the sql table considering the month an year column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a year column that contains things string value like 2015,2014, 2013, 2012, etc. A month column that  displays string value like January, Feburary,...December. I need to run a select that sort the table considering the both Year and month column. Can anyone provide some input? Is the any system procedures to do it easily.

I want the output based on the Year and Month descending Order.

Comment: is this mysql or sqlserver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
order by cast(year as int) desc
         ,case when month = 'January' then 1
               when month = 'February' then 2
               ....
               when month = 'December' then 12
          end desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ORDER BY CAST(month+year AS DATE) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 DECLARE @table TABLE
      (
         year  VARCHAR(10),
         month VARCHAR(20)
      )

    INSERT INTO @table
    VALUES      ('2015',
                 'January'),
                ('2015',
                 'March'),
                ('2015',
                 'February'),
                ('2015',
                 'April'),
                ('2015',
                 'May'),
                ('2014',
                 'January'),
                ('2014',
                 'February'),
                ('2014',
                 'March'),
                ('2014',
                 'May'),
                ('2014',
                 'April'),
                ('2016',
                 'January'),
                ('2016',
                 'February'),
                ('2016',
                 'March'),
                ('2016',
                 'May'),
                ('2016',
                 'April')

        SELECT *
    FROM   @table
    ORDER  BY CONVERT(INT, year) desc,
              Datepart(mm, Cast(month + ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the **month name into number** for using a translation reference table and store values

```
 jan-1,feb-2,march-3 like wise
```

Then try

```
SELECT * FROM tblName ORDER BY yearField DESC, monthField DESC
```